# What does the "1" mean in the "moderator accepts moderator agreement" event in the user history?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, moderators, moderator-agreement, user-history-page

Moderators have access to a list of events which happened to or because of an action by the user.

One of those is "moderator accepts moderator agreement", and it has a comment "1 by" + my username. What does this 1 signify? Is it a version number? It's 1 on all three sites I moderate.

[image]

Comment: You check your own events? Can't you remember what you just did? Did you become a mod so you can track yourself? I'm off to the VrijMiBo ...

Comment: Probably they just use a generic function for stating the count of events in that column

Comment: @muru there's also things in there that just say 'by X'. I just looked at my own, it has the same '1 by Tinkeringbell' event for the mod agreement... but the event just before that, which states 'appointed to moderator', is just followed by  'by X'.

Comment: June 5, moderator accepts that humanity is hurtling toward inevitable doom, 1 by Glorfindel.

Comment: this must be your reply to SMS with agreement text. Don't you remember getting SMS with this text and request "respond with SMS with 0 to decline, any other text to accept"

Comment: Maybe it's the number of times you've been a moderator. Resign and get reinstated to check. Or the number of versions of the moderator agreement you've signed. Petition for a change to the agreement that everyone has to sign. All for science of course.

Comment: @Robert you made me go and check the part about reinstatements... I can't find any evidence for that.

Comment: I don't think I had to accept the agreement again on reinstatement. Can't remember if I had to specifically for MSE... either

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That would explain why there's no second event in your user history on MSE then ;)

Comment: Is there any tooltip that appears when you hover your mouse over the `1`, like it does for the post date?

Comment: @Laf nope, no tooltip

Comment: @Glorfindel Or a class name or something else when inspecting the element?

Comment: @user289905 `<td>1 by <a href="/users/18673/glorfindel">Glorfindel</a></td>`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I went digging because I was curious if this was just a `true` that you accepted the agreement. It's not.

The 1 is the version number of the Moderator Agreement that was accepted.